# App crashes then reloading tableview data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have problem with reloading my tableview.Then I delete something on my tableview, the tableview should reload and the data should go up.But then I delete something nothing happens and there some blank spaces between the rows.
I tried with tableview.deleterows but after I implemented this method my app crashes..

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

```
if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            //let mt = movieArray2[indexPath.row]

            //1
            guard let appDelegate =
                UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                    return
            }

            let managedContext =
                appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            managedContext.delete(self.movieArray2[indexPath.row])
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


            do{
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch {

            }

 }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan: This is not a duplicate question, Please check again and also you already answer this question but now you have deleted and mark as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `managedContext` before `delete` the `cell` like below:

```
do{
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    managedContext.delete(self.movieArray2[indexPath.row])
    try managedContext.save()
    self.movieArray2.remove(at:indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  } catch {

 }
```

Comment: All of the code should be in the `do` block. It logically groups together code that should go together as an atomic action.

Comment: @rmaddy: thank you, I have updated my answer

Comment: I tried this but the app crashes again with the same error.

Comment: @OzanGümüstas That's because you still need to update your local data model array in addition to Core Data.

Comment: How to update ? can u give me an example ?

Comment: @OzanGümüstas: You have to update your local data array which is use for to reload the table means from which arrray you are getting data in  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: @OzanGümüstas If you didn't get my point then show me your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection method so in this method you are returing how many number of row you want so that array also need to update with your database

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return movieArray2.count
                
    }
But moviearray2 is not an array its a Core Data object

Comment: @OzanGümüstas: You need to update movieArray2 after save the managedContext

Comment: @OzanGümüstas: You need to again fetch the data from coredata in movieArray2 after save the data